# Where to put initial configuration data of a page in React/Redux multi-page app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Where to put initial configuration data of a page in React/Redux multi-page app?

> The question originally had phrase "never changing data" instead of "initial configuration data of a page". The former were the words I used while googling answers. Now re-worded because "never changing" implies constant, which the data is not, even though not changed during a single page view. The initial data comes from a backend database. In our case injected into JSP but it could be ajax loaded in a non-JSP app.

Our case is here to further illustrate the point:

> We have a Java Spring server using JSP to generate HTML and plain jQuery JavaScript. That setup is slowly being updated to use React/Redux. Each page is an independent React app to allow easier transition.
>
> In one of the pages we show a table and 2 search filters. The search filters are a droplist of objects (id,name pair) and a datepicker. The objects are loaded as a list from the underlaying database. They never change during a single page view.
>
> We inject some initial configuration data into the JSP page, which the React app uses via `window.config = {}` such as `window.config.language = "en"`.
>
> Currently we load those droplist objects via ajax and put them into a Redux store. However, they never change after initial loading. So, we thought maybe better inject them directly into JSP as we have a place there for configuration data (`window.config.droplistObjects = []`)
>
> Almost all of our page state is in Redux apart from a few configuration items (language) and some component specific ephemeral state. All other data is loaded via ajax.

A few places comes into mind:

1. Redux store
2. React main component
3. Global variable like `window.config.droplistObjects = []`
4. Somewhere else

Comment: You could make a constants file and export that data as an array or object and import that inside of your component and use it.

Comment: Yes. The real application uses something else than countries. So contants file is out of the question. I'll revisit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Will the fixed data always come from the database? How big is it?

Comment: The amount is in a ballpark of 20-50 items and it always comes from the database. I am looking here for a more generic solution/concensus than solution to the specific case per se. We may encounter various situations later and I would like to get a good understanding prior commiting to certain way. I've googled this topic and haven't found a good general way of storing never changing data.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "constants file is out of the question". That would be the obvious solution.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what is meant by the "constants file". For me it means a js file filled with constants, which are unchanging by definition and thus not retrieved from a database. The data we fetch is not constant. It can be edited elsewhere in the app. It's just never changed during a page view. I think the word "constant" just doesn't ring right but that doesn't mean the file approach wouldn't be a good one. Could you post the constants file approach as an answer with example?

Comment: @JarnoArgillander thanks for clarifying your question. Check my answer when you get a chance. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be overthinking this: what you are already doing seems just fine to me.
This is how I see this working:

1. fetch data from db inside your Redux action
2. reducer updates the state
3. container component passes the updated status to dumb component
4. view gets updated

I don't see any problems with that. I've written at least 4 different apps with this basic structure, a couple using Firebase and a couple a ruby back end.

I'm not sure this answer your question, but I hope it helps you taking a step back and see the situation more clearly.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer and I think you may be right. I posted this question because our project members had different opinions on where to store the initial data. I don't yet have a strong opinion myself, so drawing wisdom for the community seemed like a good idea. I'll wait some weeks to see if alternative solutions emerge.